# How do I recover System files?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, hidden-file

I used the attrib command to hide a file as system, something like this-

```
attrib +s +h example.txt
```

Is they any way to recover this file without knowing the file name and/or the directory?

I mean is there any way to unhide these files like the normal hidden files (which we can do from the View tab in the File Explorer). Also if we somehow forget the file name and/or directory, is  it lost forever, or is there any way to recover it.

Comment: Suppose I know the folder- So can I see all the files in it using file explorer?

Comment: any innate way in windows?

Comment: +s is not a reference to super, its a reference to system. You turn it into a system file/folder, doesn't make it even more hidden

Comment: I have amended it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a command prompt, run `dir /a:sh` which lists our all files marked as system and hidden. Once you see the file in the list, set the attrib flags back.

An alternative (thanks LPChip) is to enable `Show hidden files, folders and drives` from the below dialog, which you can get to from Windows Explorer > View > Options > Change folder and search options.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This was the exact thing I was looking for. BTW is there any hope to do this using File Explorer?

Comment: If you enable show hidden/protected OS files, these will also show up in explorer.

Comment: @batchcoding____s see the updated answer with the dialogue you need to get to.

Comment: Is a "super hidden file" as OP described really called that? I wouldn't say it's super hidden if the "Show hidden files" option had it show up.

Comment: There's no such thing as super hidden.

Comment: @spikey_richie   I have approved your edit as well as edited the body of the question.

Comment: You need to also uncheck the `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` to show files and folders with the system and hidden attribute set.